# How to launch browser from Java WS and log on page by SSO?

Tags: java, session, jboss, java-web-start, saml

I have an Java Web Start application which communicate with J2EE server application (JBoss). User is logging in (login & password) and after that doing some operations.

Now I would like to add a functionality to this program in order to launch from its menu default web browser with some page of user's context data **via single sign-on**. I mean:

1. (Assume my Java WS app is a bank application).
2. User logs in and clicks an option in app main menu.
3. Java app launches user default browser with (for example) stock exchange page with user's data (eg: his securities). What is important, user doesn't need to type login and password on webpage - logging has to be done underneath by SSO.

I know how to make this on my own (for example: transfer some token to page), but my question is: is there any **world-wide standard** by which I'm able to do this? I really need to care about security. Maybe my solution has some defects that I can't see now.

I heard a little about SAML "protocol" but I'm not sure I could use it in my case, because:

(according to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language#The_SAML_Use_Case)

- if I make "Request SSO Service" from JWS app first, connect to JBoss and create "XHTML form" on server, and later send it back to JWS: how open the browser and send POST "XHTML form" ("Request the Assertion Consumer Service") automatically, right after browser launch? Is it possible from JDK?
- or if I first open the browser instead and connect to JBoss: how to transfer user session from JWS app to browser? I tried to add ";JESSIONID=4959...." to URL and get session by request.getSession() on server side, but new session was created :/

So, is it possible to meet the requirements this way?
Maybe is some good standardised solution?

Thanks in advance for answers :)